# How to configure lvm from dracut emergency shell?

Tags: lvm, dracut

I am sorry if this is a silly question or someone has already answered it.

I am new to linux and encounter a problem with booting into OS (Qubes OS 4.0.1). After some time searching about the problem, I found a [possible solution](https://github.com/QubesOS/qubes-issues/issues/5160) (comment by notbyosmosis). However, in the guide they said to modify lvm config file.

After I typed "/etc/lvm/lvm.conf" I got the following message:

```
sh: /etc/lvm/lvm.conf: Permission denied
```

I didn't manage to find information on how to get the permission. All the suggestions I've found require to do everything from os.

Is there a chance to get the permission without reinstalling the os?

OS partition is encrypted if it's matter.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: By typing `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` you are trying to *run* the `lvm.conf` file, which is not possible since it is a configuration file, not an executable. You will need to start a text editor to modify the file, e.g. `nano /etc/lvm/lvm.conf` if yor system has the `nano` text editor available (it's quite small and user friendly, so it might be installed by default).

Comment: Hello @telcoM and thank you for the explanation! Unfortunately, I don't have nano, vim, or emacs installed on my dracut emergency shell.

Comment: I've tried to access the file from OS installed on a USB driver, but I didn't success in finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it was a silly question.

It turned out that I have vim on my pc, however I tried to run it via 'vim' instead of 'vi'.

Now my problem is solved and I can successfully boot into my os.